# Extracting geo-coordinates for List of Addresses (VBA EXCEL)

Tags: vba, excel

I have a large list of locations that I need to find the latitude and longitude for to use in another application. I've created some code to go to a website and retrieve this information. The first coordinate is placed fine most of the time. However, not all the addresses are recorded in excel. Sometimes I'll get empty cells. I can't seem to figure out what's wrong. Here's is the code:

```
Sub GetCoordinates()
    Dim IE As New InternetExplorer
    Dim Doc As HTMLDocument

    Dim rowNum As Integer
    Dim lastRow As Integer

    Dim tURL As String
    Dim coordinates As String

    IE.Visible = True

    'This will be the number of rows with an address (5 is for testing purposes)
    lastRow = 5

    For rowNum = 1 To lastRow
        'The URL is determined by the address in a cell (ex. in C2)
        tURL = "http://dbsgeo.com/latlon/?" & Cells(rowNum, "C").Value
        IE.navigate tURL

        Do
        'Wait until the page loads
        Loop Until IE.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE

        Set Doc = IE.document

        coordinates = Trim(Doc.getElementById("latlon").innerText)

        Cells(rowNum, "B").Value = coordinates
    Next rowNum

    IE.Quit
End Sub
```

It's not that the code doesn't run; The problem is I'll get coordinates for say 3 out of 8 addresses, in random order. There are even times when the wrong coordinates are recorded. I don't know why it's like that. Can someone tell me what's wrong with my code?

Comment: You're pulling coordinates in to a variable `coordinates` but then assigning a value to `Cells(rowNum, "B")` with a variable `sDD` which is not defined in the scope of this subroutine. If this is a global variable that is used elsehwere, that might be your problem, otherwise I do not understand how this code could possibly return any information.

Comment: The sDD was supposed to be replaced by coordinates, my apology. I'm pulling the coordinates from an element on the webpage (with id "latlon") and storing that in another column in the excel sheet using Cells(rowNum, "B").

Comment: Have you verified that `coordinates` always returns a value?

Comment: That's part of the problem I'm having: There are times when it's not returning anything, and even returning the wrong information. 

On a random run:
So for Ottawa it returns -> 45.42152960082702, -75.69719309918582, and for Vancouver -> 49.26122600168588, -123.1139267992694. For Toronto -> 18.547324589827422, -72.388916015625 (which is wrong),

while on another run: For Ottawa -> ""

Comment: You need a better way to wait for the page to load, I am trying some things here but it is still not working as I expect.  The page is not finished loading even though the `.ReadyState = ReadyState_Complete`...

Comment: I'm also thinking it's a webpage issue. I don't know what specifically though.

Comment: Do you need to clear variable data in VBA? Doesn't it overwrite it?

Comment: Also, instead of writing the address to the URL, can I add the address to a field? I have another webpage that I can get the coordinates from, but I have to add the address to a text box to get anything: http://itouchmap.com/latlong.html

Comment: ahh yes, it should overwrite but maybe if the page has not fully refreshed it is still pulling in the "old" values...

Comment: Replacing the Do-Loop to check if the page is loading with Application.Wait (Now() + CDate("00:00:10")) seems to work better, but it would take hours if I had to wait 10 seconds for each address. Even then, I can't be sure if the coordinates are right... Do you know of a better way to insert data into, and get it from a webpage?

Comment: right you don't want to wait 10 seconds you only want to wait until the page is actually finished loading. I know of a better way but that is the problem, it is not working at the moment, so I am trying to figure out what else it could be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be that those fields `"latlon`" for example, are being populated by some javascript functions which aren't executed until *after* the page has loaded, so relying on the `IE.document.readyState` is not reliable in this instance.

Ordinarily, I say use the WinAPI sleep function (put this at the top of your module):

```
Public Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)
```

Then, do your "waiting" loop like:

```
Do
   Sleep 250
Loop Until IE.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE And Not IE.Busy
```

This was still not working for me for this particular website, though, although if I did `Sleep 1000` that seemed to work, the timing will vary based on traffic, network speed, connectivity, available system resources, etc., so even that is not 100% reliable.

I also tried to find a way to emulate the XMLHTTPRequest (which is faster than using the browser directly) but this was also not working.

I looked at the other site. It is possible to fill forms and submit/click controls on a website using VBA, for the most part, but I never found those to be very reliable and didn't try that site.

**I spent waaaaay too much time trying to force that solution to work,** but it is a bad solution because it's a bad website that's hacked together by some 3rd party using Google's Geocode API.

**You should just use Google's API directly**

Documentation:

https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/geocodingupgrade

You can construct a URL like:

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=Paris,+France

You can load that to an XML/DOM parser (use a vba reference to Microsoft XML, v6.0 (aka MSXML2) which is what I would recommend.  This does not use a browser, it is a stream that is capable of loading an XML from a url (like above) directly in memory.

With a DOM parser, use the DOMDocument's `.GetElementsByTagName("location")(0)` and then pull the lat/lon from the child nodes.

Let me know if you have trouble implementing that.

Comment: Thank you for the time you put into this. I was wondering why I was getting the wrong coordinates even after the page apparently loaded. Because of time, I ended up creating a 15 second delay between each address with my previous code and running it overnight. This was just for testing purposes, since it's not reliable if some of the addresses might be wrong. I will now use Google's API to get the data so I can use it properly.

Comment: You're welcome! While you can probably parse the HTML in an IE Browser, I have figured out how to do it much faster with Google's API, using DOM to parse the returntext from an XMLHTTPRequest.  If you're interested in that let me know.

Comment: Yep, I did it with the XML and it's SO much faster. Created a 1 second delay between each request, since Google would sometimes not give me the address if I made too many requests. Don't mind waiting a couple of minutes for the whole thing to run, as opposed to over an hour for the last one. :) Thanks!

Comment: Also compared my results with the ones from the previous night (using the browser method), they corresponded quite well, except for a few entries.